# How do I use String.iter in F#

Tags: string, loops, f#

I cannot find any examples of String.iter so I've been looking at Seq.iter and Array.iter's examples and trying to apply it to chars in a string but I just can't get it right. Could somebody please give me an example on how to use String.iter. I need to do functions with each char in a string.

Here is what I was doing previously but I know this can be improved on and made way more efficient, I don't want to have to convert a string to a char list just to cycle through it.

```
let chars = [ 'a'; 'b'; 'c' ]
let mutable result = 0

for c in chars do
    match c with
    | 'a' -> (result <- result + 1)
    | 'b' -> (result <- result + 2)
    | 'c' -> (result <- result + 3)
    | _ -> printfn "test"

printfn "result of %A is %d" chars result

System.Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, F# has type `string` (which is a .NET type) and this is distinct type from `char list` (which is a functional F# list of characters). In your example, you are creating a list of characters, so you can best process it using functions from the `List` module.

Regarding iteration - in your case, you are accumulating some state and so `iter` is not the operation you need (`iter` is used for performing some imperative action for each element).

To solve your specific problem, the nicest option is to use `List.sumBy`:

```
let result = chars |> List.sumBy (fun c ->
    match c with
    | 'a' -> 1
    | 'b' -> 2
    | 'c' -> 3
    | _ -> 
        printfn "test"
        0 )
```

The `sumBy` function sums the numbers returned for each element and so you just need to return 1, 2 or 3. In the remaining case, we print (leaving the same side-effect) and return 0 because we just want to keep the same sum.

More generally, you could use `List.fold` which lets you accumulate results as you iterate over the list:

```
let result = chars |> List.fold (fun result c ->
    match c with
    | 'a' -> result + 1
    | 'b' -> result + 2
    | 'c' -> result + 3
    | _ -> 
        printfn "test"
        result ) 0
```

In all of these, you can replace `List.` with `Seq.` because functions in `Seq.` work on any sequence (lists, arrays, strings, etc.). This might be a bit slower, but that's typically not an issue. The `String` module has fewer functions and you could use it if you defined your input as `"abc"` rather than `['a';'b';'c']`

**EDIT:** To answer the questions in comments, if you can use `Seq.sumBy` directly on a string and you can use `int` to convert a character to its numerical code, so you can use that to eliminate pattern matching (this handles all characters in the same way, you might want to filter invalid ones out using `Seq.filter` first, depending on what logic you're implementing):

```
let str = "abc"
let result = str |> Seq.sumBy (fun c -> (int c) - 96)
```

Comment: Thank you for these solutions, but is it not possible to iterate through a string without having to first convert the string into a char list? Also would it not be possible to add to the result variable by using the value of the index instead of having to write all chars down in the match expression?

Comment: Thank you so much! One last question, could you explain the 96?

Comment: @Alanay The ASCII code of lower-case `a` is 97 (and subsequent letters have increasing codes), so this just turns `a` into 1, `b` into 2, etc.